# AWS Lambda timeout while trying to upload updated node zip file

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

The zip file size , that has my updated function code, is around 7 MB. I have tried several times to upload it via both methods - Zip, and S3. I consistently get an error message : timeout of 61000ms exceeded.

I tried publishing a new version of the lambda function and tried again with the same outcome. Any suggestions?

Comment: How do you upload the file? from the cli or the AWS dashboard?

Comment: What is the region of you Lambda Function? And can you paste the content of ~/aws/config file without the credentials?

Comment: If you're also having trouble uploading the file to S3 then you might have a bad internet connection. Can you show the command line you are using to upload the file?

Comment: I am uploading it via web interface - AWS dasboard .  The region is : us-west-2

Comment: Like I mentioned in the issue description, I am able to upload to S3. But even uploading via S3 doesnt seem to work.

Comment: So you're able to upload to S3, but uploading to S3 doesn't work? Those statements seem to be mutually exclusive. Have you tried using command line tools instead of just the web interface? Where are you located? This really sounds like it's just an internet connection issue.

Comment: I think there is some confusion.Here is the full story , while updating my existing lambda function, I download that function onto my PC. It is downloaded in zip format. I make the change and compress it back into a zip file. Then i proceed to upload it directly via the web interface selecting upload Zip file. That times out. Then I upload the zip to an S3 bucket. And in Lambda, select upload via S3 URL. That times out as well. I have a 15 Mbps line, so I doubt it'll be connection speed. I'll give command line a try.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, even upload zip to  s3 and give s3-url in lambda-function. but it keep saying timeout error.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be an issue with the AWS console that started recently. I ran into the same problem and I get this error when trying to upload code that I successfully updated in the past through the console. I see others reporting this issue on the AWS forums with no resolution posted. In my case I can update functions with small zip files without problem; the zip files that are larger (i.e. several MB or more) fail with this error.

I was able to upload the new code through the AWS CLI without any problems. Here's an example of the syntax, in my case uploading from a Windows machine.

```
aws lambda update-function-code --function-name MyFunctionName --zip-file fileb://C:/Temp/function_package.zip
```

You can find the full syntax in the [AWS CLI documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/update-function-code.html).

Answer (score 2):

I have tried uploading the zip from a different network and that worked. Now, when I try to upload the same file via my network, works as well. This is def. something related to AWS.

Answer (score 0):

Even I had issue while uploading java jar file in aws lambda function from aws ui console.It worked when I tried from aws command line

aws lambda update-function-code --function-name HappyMoments --zip-file fileb:///home/

Steps to install aws console
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html